Multicollinearity between outcome and predictor?
I have a panel study of US counties. My outcome of interest is "homicide rate among men aged 15 to 40". I want for one of my control variables to be "% of the population that is men aged 15 to 40." Would this constitute a problem?

Why would it? Don't we like when the predictors align with the outcome?

While I can think of some problems with this analysis, collinearity is not one of them. Collinearity is a linear relationship among two or more independent/predictor variables. The outcome variable is irrelevant. You've only listed one predictor, so collinearity can't occur. As Dave pointed out, a relationship between predictor and outcome is a good thing (almost all the time).
What problems are there here? The one that leaps to mind is directly related to what I wrote above: You have only one predictor. That's way too simple a model for this sort of complex problem. Maybe this is just an exercise for class or something (in that case, please add the self-study tag) but if this is a "real" study, then you will need covariates. E.g. % urban, unemployment rate, median income, etc.)
Another problem is use of counties. If you are using all US counties, then you can run into problems with rates, because some counties have very few people. Then there may be 0 or 1 homicide per year, giving hugely different rates.

You’ve only mentioned two variables. One is outcome (homicide rate) and the other is a predictor (population proportion)
Multi-collinearity is when multiple variables are highly correlated.
If none of your other predictors correlate with population proportion, this should not be a problem.
Say you are regressing:
homicide_rate = a + bdrug_abuse + cpopulation_proportion + e
“b” here is the average of slopes that you’d draw between homicide_rate and drug_abuse for each population_proportion.
A positive “b” would indicate that more % of people are vulnerable to drug abuse, on average.
I assume the confusion you have is about using homicide_”rate”, where you use the population in the denominator. But this changes nothing but what you are predicting — what additional % of 15-40 population would be vulnerable to homicide would be there for a unit increase in drug use, on average.
If you instead take number of homicides as your outcome variable, the regression coefficient would still be interpreted similarly — how many more victims of homicide would be there for a unit increase in drug use, on average.

Notice that taking the number of homicides as your outcome variable will cause a significant difference in the diagnostics used for testing whether the regression satisfies the standard OLS assumptions. It will be difficult satisfying them. So, if you do use counts, you're better off using a glm. If you're not familar with glm's, I highly recommend john fox's applied regression text and companion. Actually, glms were in the companion like 10 years ago. He updates often enough that it's worth checking whether glms are still in the companion. Don't just purchase it and then be disappointed.
